# Why is my if and else if statement not working?

Tags: c

I was trying to solve a hacker rank problem and this one seemed pretty easy but it gives this error:

```
Solution.c: In function ‘hurdleRace’:
Solution.c:43:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
```

```
int hurdleRace(int k, int height_count, int* height) {
    int doses = 0;
    int maxH = height[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < height_count; i++) {
        if (maxH < height[i]) {
            maxH = height[i];
        }
    }
    
    if (k >= maxH) {
        return 0;
    } else if (k < maxH) {
        doses = maxH - k;
        return doses;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"is making the compiler give a problem"* - And what is the problem?

Comment: Using consistent spacing and indentation would be a good start.  If your editor won't auto-indent your code for you, switch to one that will.

Comment: `else if(k<maxH)` is redundant in this case and can be replaced by `else`.

Comment: In particular, your `return 5;` is outside the `for` loop, even though your indentation makes it look like it's inside.  So that will always be executed after the `for` loop, and your `if (k>=maxH)` code is never reached.

Comment: Please also clarify your question in the paragraph; it is a run-on sentence which is hard to understand.  Clarity and grammar are important in English as well as programming!

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean by "the compiler is wrong" but a guess (not knowing the question) is that you'll get "Wrong Answer" from the **multiple outputs** from `printf("maxH: %d\n", maxH);`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: There definitely are some questions as to what the rationale was behind that `return 5;` in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry everyone, the return 5 was not intentional, I was trying to find the problem

Comment: I just updated the code and the error that the compiler gives, and removed the extra lines that I had added.

Comment: In your code, you specify what should be returned when `if (k >= maxH)` is true. Later, you also specify what should be returned when `if (k < maxH)` is true. However, you do not specify what should be returned when both conditions are false. Although it is logically not possible for both conditions to be false, the compiler is not smart enough to notice this. If you change `else if (k < maxH)` to simply `else`, then this should solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Hmmm. I'm used to the compiler being that smart.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you, I have been talking to AI chats for like 3 hours trying to understand what is wrong because I covered both conditions but I guess humans are better after all.

Comment: @Joshua: Compilers are generally very smart regarding optimizations, and during optimizations, I'm quite sure that the compiler would notice that all code after the `else if` statement is unreachable. However, I guess the compiler is less smart regarding determining whether all control paths return a value. Actually, in C, in contrast to C++, it is legal for a function returning `int` to reach the closing brace `}` without returning a value. I guess HackerRank is using special compiler options which emit an error message instead of a warning in this case. Or maybe a C++ compiler is being used.

Comment: Standard disclaimer in these situations: competition sites like HackerRank and Leetcode are poor ways to learn how to program.

Comment: a stylistic point, but I'd move `return doses;` even out of the `else` block all the way to the bottom. Functionally it's the same, so pulling it out of all indentation blocks IMO makes it clearer to see there is an unconditional return, and thus all paths return a value.

Comment: one more minor point, you can do `for (int i=1; ...` because you've already initialized `maxH = height[0]`, no point in comparing to `height[0]` in the loop.

Comment: @yano, you're better off going with the `else` and getting rid of `doses` entirely. It only gets used once and that value is immediately returned.

Comment: instead of last six lines `return (k < maxH) ? maxH - k : 0;`

Comment: @Chris sure, many ways to do it.. could also replace the entire `else` block with `return maxH - k`. yvs2014's one liner would be my personal preference. OP can decide what's most clear to them.

Comment: Initialize `int maxH = k;` and you no longer need `if (k >= maxH) { return 0; } else if (k < maxH) {` as maxH is already bounded to be at least k.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overly complicated, but that's not the point here.

```
int hurdleRace(int k, int height_count, int* height) {
    int doses = 0;
    int maxH = height[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < height_count; i++) {
        if (maxH < height[i]) {
            maxH = height[i];
        }
    }
    
    if (k >= maxH) {
        return 0;
    } else if (k < maxH) {
        doses = maxH - k;
        return doses;
    }

    return 0; //<<<<<<<<< add this and the program will compile
}
```

Your code is compiled with the `-Werror=return-type` compiler flag, which will trigger a compile error when a non void function ends without a `return some_value` statement.

In your original code the `return 0; //<<<<<<<<< add this` line is missing, and the compiler therefore thinks that the function might end without a return statement, in which case the function would return an undetermined value. This would of course only occur if neither `k >= maxH` nor `k < maxH` are true which obviously can never happen, but apparently the comopiler is not smart enough to detect this, and therefore issues the error.

Comment: Adding `return 0;` is a suboptimal workaround. Changing `else if (k < maxH)` to `else` is better. The former adds unnecessary code and leaves the program prone to error if somebody edits `k >= maxH` to something else but overlooks the fact that `k < maxH` needs to be changed to match. (Perhaps unlikely in short code, but students should learn good habits not for working on longer code later.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, of course the code is terrible, this is just for illustrating the problem. The code should be rewritten as numerous comments already suggest.